# BBcode gem for ruby on rails (BB-ruby) - change default size of youtube video?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bbcode

Pretty much as the titles says.

I'm using the `BB-ruby` gem for BBcodes and I've got a little problem with the `[youtube]` tag.

How can I change the default size of the embedded youtube video that the `[youtube]` tag renders from `BB-ruby`? It's really small now, so I need a way to resize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can't pass options to the [youtube tag](https://github.com/cpjolicoeur/bb-ruby/blob/master/lib/bb-ruby.rb#L173), you probably need to override the method. See if the following works:

```
module BBRuby
  @@tags.merge('YouTube' => [
      /\[youtube\](.*?)\?v=([\w\d\-]+).*\[\/youtube\]/im,
      '<object width="320" height="265"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/\2"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/\2" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="320" height="265"></embed></object>',
      'Display a video from YouTube.com',
      '[youtube]http://youtube.com/watch?v=E4Fbk52Mk1w[/youtube]',
      :video])
end
```

And change the `width` and `height` in the above code.

Comment: I found out that I actually could override it with some CSS, which was abit simpler than your method. Tho your method worked fine too when I tested it. Thanks for the awnser :)